# How to get dictionary objects from a list of tuple objects?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have following list of tuple objects :

```
z = [set([33, u'11:22:33:44:55:ff']), set([12, u'11:22:33:44:54:ce'])]
```

I want to have following list of dictionary objects out of it :

d = [{33 : '11:22:33:44:55:ff'}, {12, '11:22:33:44:54:ce'}]

**Please see -- I want to use first element of set, as dictionary key**.

Can someone suggest me a code snippet, for how to perform this ?

**Edit**

Sorry it is a list of two element set objects (and not list of tuple objects).

Comment: Those aren't tuples; those are two-element sets.  How is your code supposed to tell which element of the set to use as the dictionary key and which as the value?

Comment: In response to your edit: There is no "first element" of a set; it's an *unordered* collection.  True, you could iterate over the set and take the first element of the sequence as the first element of the set, but the ordering used when iterating is completely arbitrary and implementation defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sets are unordered.  There is no "first" element of the set.

You will have to enforce some ordering on them - checking the type works:

```
dict(sorted(x,key=lambda k:isinstance(k,int),reverse=True) for x in z)
Out[33]: {12: u'11:22:33:44:54:ce', 33: u'11:22:33:44:55:ff'}
```

Comment: Instead of turning the sets into ordered lists, it may be better to go find the code that's producing sets and make it produce tuples instead. It doesn't really make sense for these inputs to be sets.

Comment: That is almost certainly the correct solution, yes.  There is always the possibility that the OP doesn't control the code producing the bogus input though.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of sets, not list of tuples.  If you want to use tuples, your list `z` should be:

```
z = [tuple([33, u'11:22:33:44:55:ff']), tuple([12, u'11:22:33:44:54:ce'])]
```

Then the following code should work

```
d = dict()
for item in z:
    d[item[0]] = item[1]
```

Comment: this will throw an error, because sets are not subscriptable

Comment: @jshanley: It won't throw an error, because it's assuming that `z` is actually a list of tuples.  It's still technically not the right answer, though.

Comment: ah sorry, I read that too fast, I didn't realize you had converted them to tuples